# how to fetch the data from database in hive on hive CLI

Tags: hive, hiveql

i have **final table** in hive in which there are 3 columns **Date,Time,A**
and  date column contain multiple days and time column contain 24 hours data  like this

```
      Date        Time         A
      2019-04-01  00:00:00    abc
      2019-04-01  01:00:00    dqh
      2019-04-01  02:00:00    hh
         ...        ...        ...
      2019-04-28  00:00:00    afger
      2019-04-28  01:00:00    rrq
      2019-04-28  02:00:00    rger
```

Now i want the fetch the data between 2019-04-25  00:00:00 to 2019-04-27 19:00:00 in hive. **I am not using Coludera**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the HQL like below:

```
select * from table where concat(Date,' ',Time)>='2019-04-25 00:00:00' and concat(Date,' ',Time) <'2019-04-27 19:00:00'
```

Comment: can you explain how concat work in this query.. @Shawn.X

Comment: concat is the function to join strings, for example, concat('ab','cd','ef') will return the result 'abcdef', so the SQL above, concat(Date,' ',Time) will return the 'yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss' format data.